# How to troubleshoot Bonjour resolution problem

Tags: bonjour

I'm having an issue where HomeKit stops working in my house.

I have four devices involved:

1. My Wireless Router - a Netgear R6220
2. My Mac Mini - running Homebridge (it's a software implementation of homekit that allows to publish your own homekit devices
3. My AppleTV - acts as a HomeKit hub
4. My iPhone - HomeKit remote - works inside and outside of the network due to the HomeKit hub

HomeKit will work just fine for months at a time, and then suddenly I will get a message from the Home.app on iOS saying that *No accessories responding*.

I have also noticed that when this happens, I cannot resolve any services that rely on Bonjour - mini.local is not ping-able from my iPhone and airplay services of the Apple TV aren't discoverable.

Since HomeKit and Airplay both rely on Bonjour, this tells me that it's an issue with Bonjour.

I downloaded the Bonjour Browser Discovery app and ran it when things were not resolvable over bonjour, but low and behold all services seem to be found by the app.

Now for the really strange part - the problem can be fixed by rebooting the Router OR the Apple TV.

So which device is the culprit?

Any advice on how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Does turning Wi-Fi off and on your iPhone fix this as well?

Comment: No. I can take my phone out of the equation entirely and Siri on the Apple TV will still not be able to find my lights.

Comment: Turn IGMP snooping off on your router, maybe? https://community.netgear.com/t5/Smart-Plus-Click-Switches/Bonjour-Service-Discovery-Problems/td-p/1380173

Comment: Did you solve your issue?